# overriding default package using xwork in Confluence v5.8.5

Tags: confluence

I need to override **login** action of **default** package. Previously i was using **Confluence conveyor plugin** to override action but not able to override by **versioning issue**.

Somehow i have come to override some action by using **xwork** but not getting how to override any action of default package.

here is my code...

```
<xwork name="XWork Create" key="xwork-create">

    <package name="default" extends="default">
        <interceptor-ref name="validatingStack"/>
        <action name="login" class="com.atlassian.confluence.user.actions.LoginAction" method="doDefault">
            <result name="input" type="velocity">/templates/plugin/login.vm</result>
        </action>
    </package>

    <package name="users" extends="default" namespace="/users">
        <default-interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        <action name="viewmyprofile" class="in.atlassian.confluence.plugin.Login">
            <result name="success" type="velocity">/templates/plugin/login.vm</result>
        </action>
    </package>

</xwork>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow its done by replacing package name with "loginDefault"...
forget to answer...

Comment: Is that all you had to do? Does putting the xwork tags as above override the com.atlassian.confluence.user.actions.LoginAction class?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a servlet filter to override default behaviour

```
<servlet-filter name="Login Filter" key="loginFilter"
                class="com.example.confluence.plugins.xxx.servlet.filter.LoginFilter"
                location="before-dispatch"
                weight="10000">

    <url-pattern>/login.action*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/dologin.action*</url-pattern>

    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</servlet-filter>
```

Then use `com.example.confluence.plugins.xxx.servlet.filter.LoginFilter` to redirect to another servlet or **xwork** action.

Perhaps something like this:

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter
{
    public void init(FilterConfig config) {}

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
                         ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            try {
                ((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect("/path/to/your.action");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // log.error(" ++ Couldn't redirect: " + e.getMessage());
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
    }

    public void destroy() {}
}
```

Thsi would have the advantage of not relying on Conveyor, which I'm fairly sure is no longer supported by its author David Peterson, or by ServiceRocket.